# Refining my database select

Tags: php, mysql

**GOAL:**

Select from the database to target a team name from one of my five specific columns. the table has a number of columns 5 of which are headed `respondent_team_1` to `respondent_team_5`. In each of those columns there maybe a string value that is repeated so the idea is to look at that columns and know this and just take the 1 distinct value and not all so I can match up the data like so:

**CODE:**

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT distinct respondent_team_1 FROM respondent_data WHERE dashboard_id = $user_dash_id";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            echo $row["respondent_team_1"];                         
        }
    }
?>
<br>
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT distinct respondent_team_2 FROM respondent_data WHERE dashboard_id = $user_dash_id";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            echo $row["respondent_team_2"]; 
        }
    }
?>
<br>
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT distinct respondent_team_3 FROM respondent_data WHERE dashboard_id = $user_dash_id";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            echo $row["respondent_team_3"]; 
        }
    }
?>
<br>
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT distinct respondent_team_4 FROM respondent_data WHERE dashboard_id = $user_dash_id";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            echo $row["respondent_team_4"]; 
        }
    }
?>
<br>
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT distinct respondent_team_5 FROM respondent_data WHERE dashboard_id = $user_dash_id";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            echo $row["respondent_team_5"]; 
        }
    }
?>
```

**SUMMARY:**

What I am trying to do is refine all those code blocks into one code block as A it is messy and B there must be a better way but I am unable to find one?

I have tried various methods, the obvious being take the column names I need and make a select against them, I tried to use the GROUP BY keyword with no luck either. Im not looking for somebody to do this for me but just some wisdom or advice would be excellent.

Comment: Why do you use five seperate queries for this?

Comment: @rbr94 That is exactly what my question is about, what is the best way to refine this?

Comment: FYI: your database is called mysql

Comment: @danjbh *Normalization*. Use another table which connects the `respondent_data` and the different `respondent_team`. Your way is very *redundant*

Comment: respondent_team should be not a coulmn but a row, in a separate table, linked to respondent_data.

Comment: @rbr94 It is not a nice method I know and ideally I would have a separate table to handle this but due to client restrictions my hands are a little tied right now, normally I would separate all of this data out.

Comment: @danjbh Could you add sample data of this table to your post?

Comment: @rbr94 sure, what would you like to see?

Comment: @danjbh data from `respondent_data`